# Valgrind not showing error regarding memory region overlap

Tags: c, valgrind, memcpy, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcheck

In the process of testing all kinds of dynamic memory-related errors using [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) (or to be specific, [Memcheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind#Memcheck)), I came accross a situation where, I'm creating the memory overlap intentionally, but there is no error report from Valgrind/memcheck. Below are the codes used. Please share what I'm missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char * pOne;
    char * pTwo;

    pOne = (char *)malloc (24);
    pTwo = pOne + 4;
    strcpy (pOne, "Sourav Ghosh");
    printf("pOne = %s\npTwo = %s\n", pOne, pTwo);
    memcpy (pTwo, pOne, 16); //Overlapping issue should be here
    printf("pOne = %s\npTwo = %s\n", pOne, pTwo);

    free (pOne);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation

```
[sourav@titan temp]$ gcc -g srvtest.c -o memory
```

#### Sample run and output

```
[sourav@titan temp]$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./memory
==6982== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6982== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6982== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6982== Command: ./memory
==6982==
pOne = Sourav Ghosh
pTwo = av Ghosh
==6982== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6982==    at 0x4006817: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:275)
==6982==    by 0xAD0C0D: vfprintf (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==6982==    by 0xAD6E82: printf (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==6982==    by 0x8048477: main (srvtest.c:15)
==6982==
pOne = SourSourSourSourSour
pTwo = SourSourSourSour
==6982==
==6982== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6982==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6982==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==6982==
==6982== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6982==
==6982== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6982== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6982== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 8)
[sourav@titan temp]$
```

There is actually no information about the memory region overlap. As per the Valgrind manual, it should have showwn something like:

```
==27492== Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0xbffff294, 0xbffff280, 21)
```

What is the missing part in my case?

*System information:*

```
[sourav@titan temp]$ uname -r
2.6.18-194.el5PAE
[sourav@titan temp]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
[sourav@titan temp]$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.5
[sourav@titan temp]$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.5.0
```

Comment: Works for me (compiled with gcc 4.7.3, valgrind 3.8.1). Could the compiler have inlined the `memcpy()` (with a builtin), perhaps? you could try compiling with `-fno-builtin` and see if this changes.

Comment: Using Valgrind (valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian) and gcc ((Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5) I also get the expected Valgrind message.

Comment: @unwind just FYI, this code is a snippet from a larger code base, where all the possible dynamic memory related problem scenarios are there, including the mismatch between C/C++ allocator-deallocator. To comply with `g++`, casting is there. Anyway, thanks for the i/p. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Hasturkun, the issue was with the compiler inlining `memcpy()` with a builtin. So, valgrind was not able to hook the `memcpy()` and catch the error.

#### Modified compilation

```
 [sourav@titan temp]$ gcc -g -fno-builtin srvtest.c -o memory
```

#### Modified Output

```
[sourav@titan temp]$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./memory 
==19785== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19785== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19785== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19785== Command: ./memory
==19785== 
pOne = Sourav Ghosh
pTwo = av Ghosh
==19785== Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x402602c, 0x4026028, 16)
==19785==    at 0x4007AE2: memcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:482)
==19785==    by 0x80484B3: main (srvtest.c:14)
==19785== 
pOne = SourSourav Ghosh
pTwo = Sourav Ghosh
==19785== 
==19785== HEAP SUMMARY:
==19785==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==19785==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==19785== 
==19785== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==19785== 
==19785== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==19785== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 8)
[sourav@titan temp]$
```